# Using sed to change pom/xml element value with regular expressuib

Tags: sed

I have an XML file and I used sed to change the value of the element "own.version":

```
<properties>
    <own.version>1.1.77-SNAPSHOT</own.version>
</properties>
```

Sed statement:

```
cat pom.xml | sed -e "s%<own.version>${oldVersion}</own.version>%<own.version>${newVersion}</own.version>%" > pom.xml.transformed
```

Now my pom file is going to be more generic and properties that I want to change might be "*.own.version", e.g.:

```
<properties>
    <a.own.version>1.1.77SNAPSHOT</a.own.version>
</properties>
```

How can I use a regulare expression with sed to change the value of *.own.version?

Comment: `sed` is not meant for that, you should probably use `xmlstarlet` for this.

Comment: this change will be executed on our jenkins server, where xmlstartlet is not installed.

Comment: try to select an answer correct out of all answers to close the thread completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work, it captures any prefix of "own.version".

```
sed "s%<\(.*\)own.version>.*</%<\1own.version>${newVersion}</>%" pom.xml > pom.xml.transformed
```

The pattern is a bit simplified, too, assuming that there is only one such version to be modified (i.e., it captures all old version numbers), and the closing tag identifier is omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Since you told your Jenkins don't have `xmlstarlet` could you please try following `awk` and let me know then.

```
##Shell variable
new="1.8"
awk -v new_version="$new" '/own\.version/{sub(/>.*</,">"new_version"<")} 1' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
<properties>
    <own.version>1.8</own.version>
</properties>
```

In case want to save output into Input_file itself append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` to above code then.